# IRC bot written in Python - join channel function

Tags: python, bots, irc

I'm trying to add to my python IRC bot a function that when I type "join #channel-name" on IRC, the bot will join the channel.

Here's my code:

```
# IRC bot written by syrius
import socket

server = "irc.freenode.net" # IRC server
channel = "#syrius-test" # Channel
botnick = "syrius-bot" # Nickname of the bot
master = "syrius_" # Nickname of the bot's master
exitcode = "bye " + botnick #Text that we will use to make the bot quit

def ircwrite(message):
  global ircsock
  ircsock.send(str(message).encode('latin-1', 'ignore'))

def ping():
  ircwrite("PONG :pingis\n")

def sendmsg(chan , msg):
  ircwrite("PRIVMSG "+ chan +" :"+ msg +"\n")

def joinchan(channel):
  ircsock.send(bytes("JOIN "+ channel + "\n"))

def join():
  ircsock.send(bytes("JOIN %s"))

def hello():
  ircwrite("PRIVMSG "+ channel +" :Hello!\n")

def quitting():
  ircwrite("PRIVMSG "+ channel +" :Okay boss, leaving now.\n")


ircsock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
ircsock.connect((server, 6667))
ircwrite("USER "+ botnick +" "+ botnick +" "+ botnick +" :IRC bot coded by syrius.\n")
ircwrite("NICK "+ botnick +"\n")

joinchan(channel)

while 1:
  ircmsg = ircsock.recv(2048).decode() # receive data from the server
  ircmsg = ircmsg.strip('\n\r') # removing any unnecessary linebreaks.
  print(ircmsg) # Here we print what's coming from the server
  name = ircmsg.split('!',1)[0][1:] # We split out the name

  if ircmsg.find(":Hello "+ botnick) != -1: # If we can find "Hello Mybot" it will call the function hello()
    hello()

  if ircmsg.find("PING :") != -1: # if the server pings us then we've got to respond!
    ping()

  if name.lower() == master.lower() and ircmsg.find(":quit " + botnick) != -1:
    quitting()
    ircsock.send(bytes("QUIT \n", "UTF-8"))

  if name.lower() == master.lower() and ircmsg.find(":join %s") != -1:
    join()

main()
```

Of course the following code is incorrect :

line23:

```
def join():
    ircsock.send(bytes("JOIN %s"))
```

line56:

```
if name.lower() == master.lower() and ircmsg.find(":join %s") != -1:
    join()
```

I would like to know what should I put there so the bot can join the channel.

Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Please make your question stand alone.  IRC commands also require an end of line marker.  Do you know about b literals?  Also, what are you supplying to %s?

Comment: Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)!

Comment: HI Bear Brown, thank you for your quick reply. So for the end of line marker it would be: ircsock.send(bytes("JOIN %s\n")) ? The %s is probably incorrect since it would be the name of the channel I write on IRC to join.

Answer (score 1):

I see a couple of problems with this solution, my recommendation is you should probably try to use an IRC framework such as Pydle or one of the billion others that already handle protocol.

The first issue I see is using latin-1 for your encoding, generally you should be using utf-8, you could also be using whatever the server advertises in the CHARSET from the RPL_ISUPPORT reply, though that is not common anymore. Along the lines of encoding also, you could decode the IRC lines from utf-8 so you can deal with strings instead of bytes, and just reencode it at the output.

The next IRC issue would be your line ends, IRC messages should always end with CR-LS (Carriage Return-Line Feed) which would be the \r\n characters instead of just the \n.

The last thing I felt like mentioning was your string formatting, you should be using `"JOIN {}".format(channel)` which is the preferred string formatting method these days, unless you're using python 3.7 then you would use fstrings which are similar.

With the way you are trying to do the formatting now, you are doing it through both concatenation (eg `"USER" + channel`) but you are also trying to use old style string formatting through %s. If you wanted to use %s formatting the correct way would be `"JOIN %s" % (channel)`, though these days using .format and fstrings are the preferred method.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing argument. `ircsock.send(bytes("JOIN %s")`).

It should be like this:

```
ircsock.send(bytes("JOIN %s \r\n") % (channel))
```